# Files not saving if app is installed from APK

Tags: java, android

My App doesn't save files in internal storage if installed from APK but if installed by IDE with adb it is saving. APK generated by Build/Build APK

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "installed from APK"? Via the Play Store? Via downloading the APK and installing it manually on the device via Package Manager or similar?

Comment: When i export my app to APK by "Build APK" and then i install this apk on my phone it cant save any file. No exceptions, errors etc. just file is not saving. But when i connect my phone to computer and install it by clicking green button "play" (Shift + F10 in Intellij) everything works fine.

Comment: How exactly are you transferring your built APK to the device and installing it?

Comment: This is what I have faced. If u send the debug version via mail or whatever, u won't be able to accept the permission. You will need to make a release version for that apk.

Comment: @clownba0t installing by adb (from cmd) or sending to google docs.

Comment: @aa_oo it unfortunatelly still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. 
Don't know exactly why but when i was using

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

It wasnt working, but when i changed to:

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openOutputStream("file.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It works fine.